# can't connect client and server import.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am on a personal project to create data vizsualisation project with d3. I want to stream data from server to client where I will visualize it.

Idea is node.js + socket.io + d3.js

I have my data stream but now im testing out server data stream to client, using socket.io but I constantly fail. So i Was taking baby-steps with below mentioned code, and that also fails. (code btw is from official socket.io page)

All the time says that resource file cannot be found:

```
Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server.
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: io
```

I was playing around with so many other tutorials and examples that now im completely confused. can anybody help? Maybe other suggestions instead of socket.io

**Server:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3001, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**Client**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>


<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `/socket.io/socket.io.js` exists in your server and it has the proper rights? Check that the file is being correctly downloaded in your browser network inspector tab.

Comment: pardon for dumb question - how to properly download it? npm install inside server folders, what else?

Comment: @andris Your are mixing up node-modules for the server with the client library, see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket.io client lib can be directly loaded via CDN like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

But if you want to be independent from the internet in your client, you need to get the client lib from here  http://socket.io/download/, then place it into some folder on server and then make it publicly accessible over use() so that the Client html can GET the file, add something like this to your app:

```
var express = require('express');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

where **public** is your directory where the socket.io lib lies